# Python Pandas Dataframe subtraction previous row and column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to subtract value from a column in a dataframe I am trying to do it like this

```
for i in range(len(Numbers)-1):
    sub = Numbers.loc[i, 'Stock'] - Numbers.loc[i, 'Sold Number']
    Numbers.loc[i, 'PrepNumber'] = Numbers.loc[i+1, 'Stock'] - sub
```

but this is not working, I am getting this error

```
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('int64'), dtype('<U4')) -> None
```

Edit:

The data that I have looks something like this:

| Date | Stock | Sold Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-19 | 1255 | 1123 |
| Feb-19 | 1089 | 1051 |
| Mar-19 | 943 | 1146 |
| Apr-19 | 897 | 992 |

I would like the output to look something like:

| Date | Stock | Sold Number | PrepNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-19 | 1255 | 1123 | 957 |
| Feb-19 | 1089 | 1051 | 905 |
| Mar-19 | 943 | 1146 | 1100 |
| Apr-19 | 897 | 992 |  |

Where PrepNumber (Jan-19) = 1089 - (1255 - 1123)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`.shift(-1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to get the entry of next row, and format the formula as follows to set up the `PrepNumber` column:

```
Numbers['PrepNumber'] = Numbers['Stock'].shift(-1) - (Numbers['Stock'] - Numbers['Sold Number'])
```

With this one-line code, Pandas has already helped you calculated the results for each row without the need to put the codes in a loop.  This is the feature that Pandas provides and you should make good use of it and avoid coding in looping style as far as possible.

**Result:**

```
print(Numbers)

     Date  Stock  Sold Number  PrepNumber
0  Jan-19   1255         1123       957.0
1  Feb-19   1089         1051       905.0
2  Mar-19    943         1146      1100.0
3  Apr-19    897          992         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

your question is not clear, it'd be great if you could provide sample data and the expected results, or explain what you're trying to do a bit more in your future questions.

but if you're trying to add or substract whole columns from each other, and saving the result in a new column then try using this:

```
Numbers["PrepNumber"] = Numbers["Stock"] - Numbers["Sold Number"]
```

Also a tip, using for loops to iterate on the records of a dataframe beats the whole purpose of using pandas, and it should be avoided at all times.

Comment: I have edited the question, please have a look

Comment: check @SeaBean answer, as mentioned using shift() is the most efficient solution.